# Perl 5.005_03 does not recognize NFS files existence

Tags: linux, perl, nfs, netapp

I have implemented a new NAS filer recently, and after mounting
it on a Linux server, the Perl interpreter (version 5.005_03) is unable
to recognize the existence of files on that mount:

```
[root@server ~]# stat /newmount/testfile 
  File: `/newmount/testfile'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  regular empty file
Device: 48h/72d Inode: 9262698097446760736  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  500/ testuser)   Gid: (   500/      testuser)
Access: 2017-02-22 16:44:21.218314000 +0200
Modify: 2017-02-22 16:44:21.218314000 +0200
Change: 2017-02-22 16:44:21.218314000 +0200


[root@server ~]# perl -e 'print "File Exists\n" if -e "/newmount/testfile";'
[root@server ~]#
```

The interesting thing here, is this:

**When I try with a newer version of the
interpreter (like perl, v5.8.8) it works:**

```
[root@server ~]# perl -e 'print "File Exists\n" if -e "/newmount/testfile";'                 
File Exists
[root@server ~]#
```

What am I missing on the old Perl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's funny that v5.8.8 is not considered the old perl.

Comment: It is ... and 5.005_03 is the ancient perl.

Comment: If you have a newer Perl there, why do you care? Is this just curiosity or do you need it to work with the 5.005_03 version?

Comment: March 1999 was the release date for that version... one would have to assume if Perl is that old, that box is a few updates behind if this is indeed not just a test.

Comment: Can you give the mount command ? Some issues exist in case of fusemount. You could also use strace to see the system calls in both versions of perl.

Comment: Yeah I know it's old.. What can I do? we must be backwards compatible to old code running on old systems (such as Solaris SPARC).
This is not just a test.

Comment: @BOC The mount is with default options, in /proc/mounts it shows:

rw,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys

Regarding strace, already tried it. Couldn't spot anything other than the bottom line which is a stat64 call with the same file name and options,
followed by a write call with an answer (Perl 5.88) and nothing and at on perl 5.005_03

Comment: Did both `stat64` calls return `0`? If so, that points to a bug in Perl.

Comment: Is your file bigger than 2GB ? Support for files bigger than 2GB was recent in 5.005_03. Can you do a perl -V and check that compiler options "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" were set ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone trying to help, I found the root cause of the issue.
For anyone facing a similar issue with legacy systems, 
check if the storage exporting the NFS mounts is using 64-bit file descriptors.
In my case, switching to 32-bit file descriptors on the storage solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using Perl.

The mounted nfs directory had perms of 775 and ownership of 0:788

Account running Perl had primary GID of 402 and was also a member of 788.

Error messages indicated "does not exist or is not a directory"

I changed the primary group of the active account to 788 and it began working.

Only posting in the hopes of preventing someone else from ripping out their last remaining hairs.